# Change Tabs style, when clicking previous or continue button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When I clicked on 'continue 1' button on the first page it will direct me to second tabs. But the tab 2 header doesn't change to dark color. How should I do that?

-Another question, when i clicked on the 'continue 1' button, it directs me to second tabs, but the second tabs alignment is off. Why is it like that?

Here is the [FIDDLE](http://fiddle.jshell.net/GodRevenge/jL2fpuep/1/) example:

**HTML**

```
<div class="main-content">
      <ul class="tabs">
        <li>
          <input type="radio" checked name="tabs" id="tab1">
          <label for="tab1">1<div class="train-stop-text" id="id1">1</div></label>
              <div id="tab-content1" class="tab-content animated fadeIn">
                    1
                  <br>
                  <button type="button" class="btn" id="previous1">Previous 1</button>

                  <button type="button" class="btn" id="continue1">Continue 1</button>
              </div> 
        </li>


        <li>
          <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab2">
          <label for="tab2">2<div class="train-stop-text" id="id2">2</div></label>
              <div id="tab-content2" class="tab-content animated fadeIn">
                 2
                  <br>
                  <button type="button" class="btn" id="previous2">Previous 2</button>

                  <button type="button" class="btn" id="continue2">Continue 2</button>
              </div>
        </li>

        <li>
          <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab3">
              <label for="tab3">3<div class="train-stop-text" id="id3">3</div></label>
              <div id="tab-content3" class="tab-content animated fadeIn">
                  3
                  <br>
                  <button type="button" class="btn" id="previous3">Previous 3</button>

                  <button type="button" class="btn" id="continue3">Continue 3</button>
              </div>
        </li>
      </ul>


      </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.tabs input[type=radio] {
    position: absolute;
    top: -9999px;
    left: -9999px;
}
.tabs {
    width: 85%;
    float: none;
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
    /* margin: 75px auto; */
}
.tabs li{
    float: left;
}
.tabs label {
    /*display: block;*/
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    text-align:center;
    padding:3px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    border:2px solid #d1d9e5;
    color: #d1d9e5;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: normal;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    top: 3px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
.tabs label:hover {
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
    top: 0;
}

[id^=tab]:checked + label {
    background: #fff;
    color: #8a8f96;
    border: 2px solid #8a8f96;
}

[id^=tab]:checked ~ [id^=tab-content] {
    display: block;
    padding-left: 250px;
}
.tab-content{
    z-index: 2;
    display: none;
    text-align: left;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 140%;
    padding-top: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.5s;
    -o-animation-duration: 0.5s;
    -moz-animation-duration: 0.5s;
    animation-duration: 0.5s;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#continue1").click(function () {
        $("#tab-content3").hide();
        $("#tab-content2").show();
        $("#tab-content1").hide();
    });  
});
```

Thank you!

Comment: post your code in the question

Comment: You can view it in Fiddle, the code is a little bit long

Comment: But as a standard SO want the main part of the code to be within the question, if you post the code in a third party site and then if the site/page is gone then the future users won't be able to use the question for reference..

Comment: Sorry, get it. I will update my question again.

Comment: whether http://fiddle.jshell.net/56Lc1drx/1/ is what you are looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The darker border is associated with the checked radio button(`[id^=tab]:checked + label {}`) so mark the tab2 radio as checked

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#continue1").click(function () {
        $("#tab-content3").hide();
        $("#tab-content2").show();
        $("#tab-content1").hide();
        $('#tab2').prop('checked',true)
    });  
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/56Lc1drx/)

Comment: not proper answer! first try it out completetly @Arun

Comment: @Victor I think the problem reported by OP is handled.. but the overall solution used by OP to have custom handlers for each button is not proper... are you talking about that?

Comment: ur fiddler works only for single click, then it doesn't!

Comment: Thanks for the code, @ArunPJohny. I dont know it is just that simple. omg

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about using a pre-existing solution for this functionality?

Examples:

http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/

http://codecanyon.net/item/lush-content-slider/3918728

http://cssslider.com/

Something along these lines could save you a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the checked attribute in tab1 too so your first tab does not highlight.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#continue1").click(function () {
    console.log("asdf");

    $("#tab-content3").hide();
    $("#tab-content2").show();
    $("#tab1").removeAttr("checked");
    $("#tab2").attr("checked",true);
    $("#tab-content1").hide();
});
```

});